# How to connect internet from 2 lan?

Tags: windows, internet, lan

My server /windows server 2012/ had two network adapters.

1st adapter is connected with domain LAN
/Static ip address/

2nd adapter for Internet
/DHCP/

The problem: Internet is down... If I enabling/disabling 2nd adapter internet is ok for just 1-2 minutes then down again

What configuration I need?

please help me guys

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run (1) netsh int ip reset resettcpip.txt  and then run (2) ipconfig /flushdns   . It really would be good and proper to restart your server at an appropriate spot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have have only one default gateway configured.
In the 1st adapter, the one you have for LAN only, remove gateway IP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure only one gateway. So when internet is coming from 2nd adapter, so set it the gateway. Then you should perform a network reset `netsh int ip reset` and flush DNS cache with `ipconfig /flushDNS`.

Answer (score 0):

Since that your PC is configured with two NICs, each NIC has a default gateway. **The PC will choose the NIC with lower InterfaceMetric to send the DNS query.**

You can first use command "**Get-NetIPInterface**" to show the interfaceMetric of your two NICs.

If you want to have the access to Internet while accessing the domain resource, it is suggested that you can choose the NIC2 as the default gateway of your PC. You can use the following command to change the interfaceMetric of your second NIC. (InterfaceIndex id is the same as the previous command shows)

**Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 29 -InterfaceMetric 8**(lower than the first NIC)

For more details, please refer to:
[enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/735479/how-does-a-windows-computer-behave-when-it-has-multiple-default-gateways)